If you say "who with/who for/who by/who from," do you also say "what with/what for/what by/what from?"
I know that "Who with?", "Who for?", "Who by?", "Who from?", "Who to?", and other "Who + preposition" sentences are colloquially very common as standalone questions (following the preposition stranded word order of something like "I don't know who I got it from.") My question is: why can't I find any information about what-questions with this word order? "I don't know what to eat it with" is also a natural and common sentence for the vast majority of native speakers, so I'd think that "What with?" as a standalone question (or "what" followed by any other preposition) would be very common as well.
As a native English speaker, I actually haven't heard either of those in real life (only ever "For/with/by/from/to who(m)?" and "For/with/by/from/to what?") I learned from browsing forums about the English language that "who + preposition" as a standalone question is also a common word order in colloquial English, but what about "what + preposition?" Have you ever heard, seen, or used "What with?/What by?/What for?/What from?/What to?" or is that word order usually limited to who-questions? (If so, why?)
Edit: I'm aware that "What with" and "What for" also have other idiomatic meanings that are separate from the use cases that I am asking about.

In a BBC TV trailer is a remark that something smells. "What of?" asks another.

In There's a Hole in my Bucket is the line "With what shall I mend it?" It would normal to ask "What with?" in casual speech.

"What with?", "What by?" and "What for?" are common. But it would be "From what?" and "To what?", I think. Quite why it's that order for those two I shall leave to others to explain.

...or "Where from?" and "Where to", depending on context.

As I always find myself writing, it's possible to come up with theoretical sentences, but much better to know specific contexts and find a sentence that fits that context. "What for?" often means "for what purpose?" i.e. "why?" but it's common especially to express doubt as to the reason. "What with?" is certainly common: "Open that bottle!" "What with?" "What by/from/to" are less common, because for directions you'd probably say "From where?" or "To where?" or just "Where?" Not sure which sense of "by" you're talking about - "How?" would be better if you're asking for a means/method.

@Lambie That's what I meant, but I guess I used the wrong word. I was trying to get the point across that the "What + preposition" questions are a full two-word sentence rather than part of a larger sentence.

Basic nature over nurture: 'Apologize!' "What for?" Sometimes there's a fine line b/t for what and what for, that sociopaths cross all the time.


… do you also say "what with/what for/what by/what from?"

Colloquially, all are possible and common:
A: “Open the door!”— B: “What with? We have no key.”
A: “I need a key” – B: “What for?” (= Why? or for what purpose, or for which lock.)
A: “His body was torn to pieces. It was obvious that he had been killed.” -- B: “What by?” (by what creature/thing had he been killed.)
A: “All we need to make a boat.” – B: “What from? There is no wood on the island.”
The usual form is (i) preposition + (ii) nominal but the inverted form remains as a vestige of “herewith, therewith, and wherewith, etc.,” that are common in Germanic languages.

I'd not expect "What from?" after "It's easy to distinguish,' but it feels better in most cases ("She's been suffering a long time" / "I made a replica of the Golden Hind last year" /  ...). It's possibly a register thing. // I'd say "What by?" is less common; "He was astounded/nonplussed." ... "What by?" again sounds incongruous.

There is always an implied embedded phrase. He was astounded. Response: What [was he astounded] by? With the embedded implied bit it just don't work. [don't: said on purpose by me]
